# FCkeditor Upload Image Jquery MVC3

Tags: fckeditor

I am using FCKeditor as web editor in my asp.net mvc beta application.

I inserted FCKeditor in Create.aspx page and every function of FCKeditors works well except image file uploading from my local pc

help me!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [TinyMCE with FCKEditor File Upload Manager in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://tinymcefckfilemanger.codeplex.com/)